# How to import *.pyc file from different version of python?

Tags: python, import, version, pyc

I used python 2.5 and imported a file named "irit.py" from C:\util\Python25\Lib\site-packages directory. This files imports the file "_irit.pyc which is in the same directory. It worked well and did what I wanted.
Than, I tried the same thing with python version 2.6.4. "irit.py" which is in C:\util\Python26\Lib\site-packages was imported, but "_irit.pyc" (which is in the same directory of 26, like before) hasn't been found. I got the error message:

File "C:\util\Python26\lib\site-packages\irit.py", line 5, in 
import _irit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Can someone help me understand the problem and how to fix it??
Thanks, Almog.

Answer (score 5):

"DLL load failed" can't directly refer to the `.pyc`, since that's a bytecode file, not a DLL; a DLL would be `.pyd` on Windows.  So presumably that `_irit.pyc` bytecode file tries to import some `.pyd` and that `.pyd` is not available in a 2.6-compatible version in the appropriate directory.  Unfortunately it also appears that the source file `_irit.py` isn't around either, so the error messages end up less informative that they could be.  I'd try to run `python -v`, which gives verbose messages on all module loading and unloading actions -- maybe that will let you infer the name of the missing `.pyd` when you compare its behavior in 2.5 and 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Pyc files are not guaranteed to be compatible across python versions, so even if you fix the missing dll, you could still run in to problems.