# How to encrypt my written python code so you can't read it but only run it

Tags: python, encryption

I'm making a very simple python code , it asks you some questions and then restarts your pc based on the answers
i want to send it to some friends but i don't want them to read the code before they run it 
how can i encrypt the .py file so you can only run it but can't read or edit it ?

Comment: You might want to convert it to an exe file, it would be in binary then

Comment: Check out cx freeze

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ ?

Comment: but i want it to be .py file 
is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418341

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094534/8402369

Comment: Check the above links out. They might work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command
`python -m py_compile fileA.py fileB.py fileC.py`
It will compile all 3 named files. Replace fileA.py, etc. with your python files.
Afterwards you can run it with python  just like usually.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324871/how-to-compile-a-python-file