# How to distribute Django web app to users?

Tags: python, django, security, web-applications

I am developing a Django app to run on every client computer separately. The question is, which technologies should I use to distribute such as docker, virtual machine etc.? How can I protect the Django app's code? How can I prevent to distribute without licenses?

Comment: So give them the build version not source code itself.

Comment: Can you explain more and give me some resources?

Comment: Have you ever installed an app? did you saw the source code itself? NO! so you see the built version of code so you can use but you can't change source code (you can try but it won't be easy ) , there is some libraries for python to output `exe` version and publish it.

Comment: These .exe files that converted from Python to exe can be decompiled. So user can read the source code of the project. I installed app using version of code but at the same time I can access the source code of these projects using PyPi.

Comment: You should built some sort of way so decompiled version can't be understandable

Comment: Which way? Can you give me some references to further research?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into [Heroku.](https://www.heroku.com/) They have a free plan too so you can test it without having to pay first. Their [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/working-with-django) with django after you set up an [app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python?singlepage=true#introduction) is good too. You will find everything in their [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/) but if you get stuck, I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc) video by [Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g). Good luck

Edit: Heroku also supports [Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) but I'm not too familiar with it. Might be useful to you

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to setup app to every users computer separately. Cloud is not an option for me.