# Hiding / locking cells in Azure / Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have made a few jupyter notebooks to handle some workflows for clients and I would like to deploy them  in such a way that the clients cannot see or modify the code / functions i have written. As they have limited knowledge of python it is important that they cannot access the functions and modify the and secondly to stop them from being shared or sold on (although highly unlikely). They may run the notebooks in anaconda / jupyter notebook /lab or alternatively via Azure notebooks or some sort of jupyter hub setup.

The code mostly consists of functions that when called give a ipywdiget display where the client can choose several options of displaying their data or running different calculations. So if they only saw the widgets that would be optimal. I know that it is possible to toggle cells or to hide input but this is easily worked around and they could get to the code. Is it possible to call the function using magics from a py file that is stored somewhere that they cannot access or modify? Are there any other methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put your code in one or more external modules and then obfuscate
the modules.  See here:

[How to obfuscate Python code effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively)

You can't prevent the client from modifying the "launch code" which 
imports an external module and calls
something in the module, but you can warn/ask them not to.  Something
like in this screenshot

[image]

from https://github.com/flatironinstitute/mfa_jupyter_for_programming/blob/master/notebooks/Jupyter%20as%20a%20calculator.ipynb