# Obfuscation + Building binary/PE with PyInstaller necessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

I want to make reverse engineering my Python code difficult.

I'm curious, if I obfuscate my python code and build it as standalone executable/binary would this be redundant?

I read PyInstaller documentation and couldn't find any portions of documentation that provided information that adequately answers if variables, function names and imports are readable after building.

Will it even make it harder to reverse engineer if I obfuscate my python code before building with PyInstaller?

Comment: I looked into this recently.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively ; what have you found in your own search?