# Python "Jumble" code to make it harder to understand?

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a python script "unreadable" ?

One of the assignments I have is to write a python program that make existing python script more complex to understand, like adding unncessary codes and such

Comment: Your key search term should be "code obfuscation." See https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obfuscate Python code effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively)