# Python py_compile produces no output?

Tags: python

I am referring to this stackoverflow answer

[How to obfuscate Python code effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively)

```
python -OO -m py_compile <your program.py>
```

It said a .pyo new file should be produced but I am not getting any new file or any errors..

what is wrong?

Comment: Does it create a directory?

Comment: no directory or anything..

Comment: i'm on windows 10 pycharm venv..tried to create directly from cmd but no luck @CMinusMinus

Comment: @bawagoc25 is the problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly the root cause of this error. I have just run a test in a similar environment to yours and it works perfectly fine.

It, however, does not output a file of type `.pyc` instead, it outputs a folder named `__pycache__` in which it contains the `compiled python file`. Check if this folder is created in your directory; it is most likely that it will.

**Side note:** As someone mentioned in the comments, consider using [this](https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2) instead as it is able to recover full source code

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on macOS. I found the `__pycache__` directory here:

`/Users/Scaroth/Library/Caches/com.apple.python/Users/Scaroth/src/py/the_script.cpython-38.pyc`

I tracked this down by looking at the module's source here:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py`

Then noticed this comment:

`cfile: The target byte compiled file name.  When not given, this defaults to the PEP 3147/PEP 488 location.`

and realised `compile()` actually returns `cfile`

A `print(cfile)` yielded...

`/Users/Scaroth/Library/Caches/com.apple.python/Users/Scaroth/src/py/the_script.cpython-38.pyc`