# How to obfuscate python code to be compiled to an executeable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, obfuscation

I have been distributing my python scripts as Pyinstaller compiled executeables so that people can't steal my code, but I found that there are many tools like [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstallerexerebuilder/) which can easily decompile executeables generated by Pyinstaller. Is there any way to obfuscate this code. I have seen other people asking similar questions, but people just reply convert the code to c or c++ and compile it. This seems like it would work, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [How to obfuscate Python code effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively) for details on how to do a simple obfuscation, but the reality is that obfuscation is basically always reversible. Depending on why you are obfuscating your code there may be better ways to go about this.

If it's just to keep people from stealing your source, most people won't even go as far as the decompilation, but the SO answer above should help. Full on obfuscation even in C or C++ has issues, and usually a system exists to decompile all popular obfuscation systems.