# Cant Obfuscate With Pyarmor And Minifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, obfuscation, pyarmor

So My Code Is Like 1000 Lines Almost And When I Try To Obfuscate It With Pyarmor It Say T`he maximum size of code object is 32768 bytes in trial version`. so i want to know is there anyway to compress the code and make the size of it smaller so i can obfuscate with pyarmor and i also tried obfuscating with pyminifier that raises a error of `` charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2907500: character maps to `<undefined>` ``   is there any way to fix this i really want to obfuscate my script with pyarmor or pyminifier if there is anyway to fix this issue please tell me without purchasing any license

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

1. Pyarmor; the best way to tackle the issue is to reduce the amount of code
2. pyminifier; check if code contains non-UTF8 chars and if the file is correctly formatted

Please refer to [How to obfuscate Python code effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively), maybe something like [pyconcrete](https://github.com/Falldog/pyconcrete) will suit you.