# How to make a docker container completely unreadable

Tags: docker, obfuscation

I have made a python web application in Django.

I want to install it locally on someone's computer. But I want the code to be completely inaccessible.

Currently I run the application in a docker container.

So is there a way I can make a container completely unreadable to someone at the same time run the webserver from inside.

Comment: *Completely* unreadable, no. If the code can be run, then by definition it can be reverse engineered. It's just a matter of how much effort you're willing to put in vs. how much effort the reverser is willing to put in.

Comment: How about  setting a root password for your app container? Someone else can not log in and read your code in the container directly.

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command has unrestricted root access on the host; you can't stop someone from launching an interactive shell or Python REPL on the container instead of your program, or just finding the source code in `/var/lib/docker`.  (And nothing in Docker ever enforces user passwords; setting a root or user password is meaningless when you can `docker run -u root` anything you want.)  Consider a compiled language like Go or Rust that doesn't require you to distribute its source code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possibile. it is against the fundamentals of container architecture.

The only suggestion I feel to give you is to obfuscate the code of your python application. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively) has been deeper discussed the obfuscation topic.