# How to secure a dockerized python contiainer

Tags: python, docker, security, encryption, cython

I have a software written in python and dockerized as a container.

I want to install my software on-premise, so you know my code will be on their computer, I want to secure my code so no one could access my source code.

My question is, Is there any way I could encrypt/secure my docker container or my python code within in order to give someone the access to run it without accessing my source code?

Comment: The Python side is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code-from-being-read-by-users and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively.

Comment: There's also plenty of duplicates on the docker side of it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check them