# how can i make the script unreadable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my code to become unreadable. Let the person who wants to use it run it, but I don't want it to be able to open and read the code, how can I do that?

Comment: You can compile it to an executable.

Comment: Or you could reimplement it in `perl`. :)

Comment: Is putting it on a server (e.g. making it a web service) an option?  How about putting it in a shared Unix environment where other users have `+x` but not `+r` permission?  If the user needs to be given the actual executable file, compilation/obfuscation is the best option, but these aren't bulletproof from a security/reverse-engineering perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can't exactly make it unreadable

There is no way to make it so the user can't read your file, but we can get close.

### 1. Executables

You can use [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen).

It is very easy to compile, and you can use the command shown below:

> Make sure you install it!

```sh
pyinstaller [options] script [script …] | specfile
// or
pyinstaller
```

### 2. Byte Code

As @Gab mentioned, you can compile to byte code.

This a great solution as you don't need any external downloads, but the problem is that you must run it with the matching version of python. (Pointed out by @tdelaney).

If you want to use this solution, follow @Gab's post. (It's pretty great)

### 3. Shared Unix Environment

As @Samwise said, you can use a shared unix environment.

> How about putting it in a shared Unix environment where other users have `+x` but not `+r` permission?

`+x` - Execute

`+r` - Read

### 4. Just don't do it.

There is really **no reason** for you to do this.

The only reason I can think of is if you are making this paid, and don't want people to make illegal copies. In that case, you can use [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63028/how-do-pc-mac-games-detect-piracy) (It's about gamedev, though some of the ideas are consistant)

---

Good luck with your script!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called code obfuscation.

It is not really possible in Python but as mentioned [in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively) you could compile your code to bytecode:

```
python -OO -m py_compile test.py
```

Example:

```
$ cat test.py
print("hello")
$ 
$ python3 -OO -m py_compile test.py
$ 
$ cat __pycache__/test.cpython-39.opt-2.pyc 
a
?��a�@s
       ed�dS)ZhelloN)�print�rr�test.py<module>� 
$ 
$ python3 __pycache__/test.cpython-39.opt-2.pyc 
hello
$
```

Comment: Note that when distributing compiled byte code, you need to run it with a matching version of python.