# How can I create a locked python file that can be executed?

Tags: python

This question is just out of curiosity: Is there any way to create a python file (**.py**) which is *locked* but *executable*?

Meaning if I try to access (open) it, it will ask for a key so that the source code can't be seen or edited. But if I execute it through a terminal, it can be run. For e.g.:

```
>>> python locked_file.py
Type an integer:
```

PS: Just for clarification. My question is **not** about **converting** a **.py** file to an **executable (.exe)** or **.pyc** or **encrypted** or **obfuscated file**.

Comment: What is the enviroment you want to run on? (which OS)

Comment: No, of course not.  Python source code is just text, if Python can read it then so can any other program.

Comment: @Guy any OS which has means to execute a .py file.

Comment: As far as Linux goes, this discussion might be useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16623/file-permission-execute-only/77538

Comment: It seems like this will be possible for OpenBSD - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546810

Comment: Another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652758/how-do-i-make-my-python-project-files-unreadable.

Comment: @DavidW, as I mentioned at the last of my question. I am not asking about converting it into some unreadable or an obfuscated file. It is about locking the file like how you lock a pdf.

Comment: @TheMaskedTitan that's not quite the same - PDFs can have an owner password but *"the owner password does not [encrypt the file], instead relying on client software to respect these restrictions. An owner password can easily be removed by software, including some free online services."*  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#Encryption_and_signatures)

Comment: @slothrop, I know. I am not asking this for commercializing or for distributing the code. I just wanted to have it locked (just a first and most basic layer of security) and share it among my friends to have fun. Nothing more.

Comment: @TheMaskedTitan - the thing is that a .py file is just text and can be read in any text editor: it's not like a PDF which needs a more sophisticated app to (meaningfully) edit, so that Adobe can at least make it a pain for you to get the ability to edit it. On Unix-like systems, there are things you could do (with some caveats) that get close to what you're looking for through careful use of file permissions and sudo.

Comment: One more thought: if you want to share it with your friends for fun (which is good!) you could consider making a web-based app.  So they interact with it through the browser, the Python code itself is running on a server and they won't see any of the source code.

Comment: @slothrop, thanks. It is really a good idea. Sure, I will check it out.