# python compiled bytecode `.pyc` not compatible with every versions. can we make it general? How to remove python magic number error?

Tags: python, cpython, magic-numbers, pyc

I have compiled this `visible_code.py` file into `.pyc` compiled byte code file, then I am running the function `fun` from `.pyc` file.

```py
# visible_code.py

def fun():
    print("Hello")
```

```py
# convet to bytecode
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("visible_code.py", "secret_code.pyc")
```

Then I am deleting this file called `visible_code.py` and trying to run the function `fun` from `secret_code.pyc` in `main.py` file.

```py
# main.py
from secret_code import fun
fun()
```

Everything works perfect until I change the python version, I get error regarding magic numbers. I have used this image from a different file structure.

[image]

Is there is any way that I can create this `secret_code.pyc` file for all the python version or at least `python3`. How to get rid of this `magic numbers` error.

Comment: Not possible. You have to compile new pyc with each Python interpreter.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the .py file ?, The .pyc is trivially turned back to .py if you know the magic number (and sometimes without it), which you should know to run the code anyway, so using .pyc file instead of .py has no advantage in terms of code obfuscation.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I want to hide my code from end user so is there is any way we can achieve this in python? I know they can reverse engineer, but I want to just hide at first.

Comment: The magic number is there because the bytecode meaning changes incompatibly when the magic number changes. If you could get rid of the magic number, it would just cause other things to break.

Comment: @wim thanks do you know any reason as well why this behavior?

Comment: If there _weren't_ a magic number, Python upstream couldn't change the bytecode in backwards-incompatible ways; that would make the interpreter harder to maintain, and for no good reason. If you want to obfuscate, obfuscate _your source_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is there is another way to create a file, but end user can't see source code directly?

Comment: [How to obfuscate Python code effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344115/how-to-obfuscate-python-code-effectively)

Comment: ...really, though, there's no such thing as effective obfuscation. If a user can run it on a general-purpose computer they control, they can inspect what that computer is doing. (There's thesis-level research work on encrypted computation, but I'll believe it as practical reality only when I see it).

Comment: Among the above-linked question's answers, though, see in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/58979147/14122 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68214794/14122