# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application when importing _socket

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've seen this question asked already but I think my situation is unique. I recently installed MYSQL and since then whenever I run `python manage.py runserver` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
le>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
    from .config import AppConfig
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
    from django.core.exceptions import AppRegistryNotReady, Imprope
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
    from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import quote, unquote
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
    module = _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\ELITEBOOK\.virtualenvs\charles\lib\site-packages\d
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "c:\python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Could MYSQL be interfering with my Python installation? I tried uninstalling Python, and deleting all the files. Then reinstalling 32-bit Python but to no avail.

Comment: Open idle type `from socket import _socket`, not module issue if haven't any error.  `DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` [socket use .pyc bytecode not an DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705304/how-to-import-pyc-file-from-different-version-of-python) Check your os/python default C compiler/module.

Comment: I tried importing _socket and I receive the same message, how do I check my default compiler?

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` to `C:\Python2.7\   python.exe manage.py runserver` so you got 3 paths (Python_Path, App_path, Virtualenv_Path ). Some libraries is on shared (Single module for all pyhon versions), you can't call with default_ver_python  upper_version_python_module.

Comment: @dsgdfg Hey thanks for the response, I actually edited the question. I got it to work. I uninstalled one of the versions of Python I had and reinstalled the x86-64 version. Thank you again for the help

Comment: Please don't edit the question with solutions! Post answers instead. This makes your question seem open while you actually solved it...

Answer (score 1):

<sup>OP solved the problem themselves, this solution was edited into the question:</sup>

---

> I solved the issue, it looks like I had two versions of Python
> installed and didn't know it. I uninstalled both versions and
> reinstalled the x86-64 version